# How to get valid neighbors from a board?

Tags: function

I just started programming, and I'm trying to make a function called "verifyNeighbor" that uses a list from another function called "getNeighborLabels", which returns a list of all neighbors around a number "me" on a board of boardWidth*boardHeight (excluding negatives and duplicates). However, this returns a neighbor list that may contain invalid neighbors (eg., on a board of 5 by 5, me=0, neighbor=4 would be in the list, but is not a neighbor). That's where the "verifyNeighbors" function comes in- to return either true or false for each neighbor around "me". Ideas on how to logically approach/ start this?

Comment: Your code was poorly indented, and therefore difficult to read. Please verify that I haven't changed the meaning of your code in any way, as that's always possible with python.

Comment: You could use a separate list for each row, which would make a lot of these tests easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is not properly formatted and I can't make much sense of it. But here's a piece of code that should do what you want:

```
# Gives the x and y coordinates on the board
def coords(point, boardWidth):
    x = point % boardWidth;
    y = point // boardWidth
    return (x,y)

#inverse transform from above
def point(x, y, boardWidth):
    return x + y * boardWidth

def verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, neighbor, me):
    mx,my = coords(me, boardWidth)
    nx,ny = coords(neighbor, boardWidth)
    # if the generated neightbor has coords that are
    # off the grid, then it is invalid
    # Since x is calculated modulo boardWidth it will never
    # be less than 0 or greater than boardWidth so we only
    # need to check y
    if ny < 0 or ny >= boardHeight:
        return False

    dx = abs(mx-nx)
    dy = abs(my-ny)
    # Neighbors are points whose coordinates relative to me are:
    # (-1,-1) top left
    # (-1, 0) left
    # (-1, 1) bottom left
    # (0, -1) top
    # (0, 1) bottom
    # (1, -1) top right
    # (1, 0) right
    # (1, 1) bottom right
    # Therefore the absolute values are one of the three options
    # below otherwise it's not a neighbor
    return (dx,dy) in [(0,1),(1,0), (1,1)]

def getNeighborLabels(boardWidth, boardHeight, me):
    mx,my = coords(me, boardWidth)
    result = []
    for i in range(-1,2):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            if i == j == 0:
                continue
            p = point(mx+i, mx+j, boardWidth)
            if verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, p, me):
                result.append(point(mx+i,mx+j, boardWidth))
    return result
```

Edit: Been programming in C way too much lately. Used // for comments >_<

Edit2: Added a wgetNeighborLabels`function that passes things through`verifyNeighbor`before adding to the list.`getNeighborLabels` should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I think you need. Tested it, and it works for me.

```
def getNeighborLabels(boardWidth, boardHeight, me):
    result = [] 

   # since there's no boardHeight, the one below me is always in the resultset

    if(me > boardWidth * boardHeight - 1):
        # throw exception here
        print 'error!'        
        return null

    if(me < boardWidth * (boardHeight - 1)):    
        result += [me + boardWidth]
    if(me > boardWidth - 1):
        result += [me - boardWidth]

   # if you're in the first or last column, something special happens:
    if(not(me % boardWidth == 0)):
        result += [me - 1]
    if(not(me % boardWidth == boardWidth - 1)):
        result += [me + 1]
    return(result)

def verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, me, neighbor):
    return(neighbor in getNeighborLabels(boardWidth, boardHeight, me))
```

Note that the indices are 0-based here, so a `2 x 5` board looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Edit: I've made the mistake of forgetting the diagonal neighbors. They should not be too hard to add from here. I also like the other answer better. I'll leave this up as another way to go.

Answer (score 0):

for the given code when run in python posted by entropy gives the error stating that coord requires 3 arguments only two are given for mx,my = coords(me, boardWidth).Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly concise version which was written assuming you're using Python 2 -- so if that's not the case, a few minor things would need to be changed. I also named the function `getNeighborOffsets()` rather than `getNeighborLabels()` because that's what it's doing.

```
def xy(boardWidth, offset):
    """ x,y position from offset """
    y = offset // boardWidth
    x = offset - y * boardWidth
    return x, y

def getNeighborOffsets(boardWidth, boardHeight, posn):
    posnX, posnY = xy(boardWidth, posn)
    return (y * boardWidth + x
                for x in [posnX-1, posnX, posnX+1]
                    for y in [posnY-1, posnY, posnY+1]
                        if (x != posnX or y != posnY) and
                            0 <= x < boardWidth and 0 <= y < boardHeight)

def verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, cell, posn):
    # if both cell and posn are on board, test whether cell is adjacent to posn
    maxOffset = (boardHeight-1) * boardHeight + (boardWidth-1)
    return (0 <= posn <= maxOffset and 0 <= cell <= maxOffset and
            any(cell == offset for offset in getNeighborOffsets(boardWidth, boardHeight, posn)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def offset(boardWidth, x, y):  # for testing
        """ offset from x, y position """
        return y * boardWidth + x

    boardWidth, boardHeight = 8, 8

    me = offset(boardWidth, 0, 4)
    print sorted(getNeighborOffsets(boardWidth, boardHeight, me))

    posn1 = offset(boardWidth, 1, 5)
    print verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, posn1, me)

    posn2 = offset(boardWidth, 1, 6)
    print verifyNeighbor(boardWidth, boardHeight, posn2, me)
```